# Angular - BeforeLoginService not responding for route authorization

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am implemeting Route Authorization. I have this service:

BeforeloginService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenService } from './token.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BeforeloginService implements CanActivate {

 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
   return !this.Token.loggedIn();
 }
  constructor(private Token: TokenService) { }
}
```

TokenService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {

 private header = {
   'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'Authorization' : this.get()
 };

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, public router: Router ) { }

 get(){
   return localStorage.getItem('token') ?? [];
 }

 loggedIn(){
   const token = this.get();
   if (token == null) {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
}
```

Then I applied it in the auth-routing.module.ts

```
import { BeforeloginService } from 'src/app/services/beforelogin.service';

const routes: Routes = [
 {path: '',
 component: LoginComponent,
 children: [
 {
   path: '',
   component: AuthComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'reset-password',
   component : RequestResetComponent,
   canActivate : [BeforeloginService]
 },
 {
   path: 'change-password',
   component : ChangePasswordComponent,
   canActivate : [BeforeloginService]
 },
]}];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

When I click on **Forgot password** anchor as shown below where I have implemented it, it suppose to redirect to **reset-password** but nothing is happening.

```
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-12 text-center">
    <a [routerLink]="['/reset-password']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" class="text-light"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I remove **canActivate : [BeforeloginService]**, it redirects.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: So.. I don’t understand.. why would you need to check for a token there..?

Comment: you do not have to implement the canActivate function for non logged in user, you can add normal routing if you want to redirect to another page for resetting password

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
loggedIn(){
   const token = this.get();
   if (token == undefined) {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Still the same problem. Not working

Comment: what about if(token){ } ??